# How to split contents of p tag into a list in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to locate my desired HTML:

`html = bs.find_next('p')`

if I do:

`print(html)`

I get:

`<p>String 1<br />String 2<br />String 3<br />String 4<br /></p>`

I want to turn these strings into a list, like:

`['String 1', 'String 2', 'String 3', 'String 4']`

I had thought there was a very simple way to do this. But when I try:

`print(html.splitlines( ))`

I get:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. My question is, how can I turn the contents of this p tag into a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

```
str(html).split('<br />')[1:-1]
```

Comment: This gives me: TypeError: `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: If it without the subscript, like `print(str(html).split('<br />')` it does turn it into a list, but the whole string is returned as one list item.

Comment: yeah because we are not using it in print let me find a good solution for you.

Comment: Aha... if I remove the space from the <br /> in your example it works as desired. Thanks!

Comment: most welcome kindly accept and upvote answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use split() and strip() methods this way:

```
x.strip('<p>').strip('<br /></p>').split('<br />')
```

> Result

```
['String 1', 'String 2', 'String 3', 'String 4']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

html = '<p>String 1<br />String 2<br />String 3<br />String 4<br /></p>' 


if type(html) == BeautifulSoup:
    print(html.get_text(separator='*', strip=True).split('*'))
else:        
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')        
    print(soup.get_text(separator='*', strip=True).split('*'))

['String 1', 'String 2', 'String 3', 'String 4']
```